# Does HTML attribute 'alt' work with numbers?

Tags: html, alt

In this [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_attributes_alt) a value of alt attribute is not demonstrated until it contains a number. So, this line does not work:

```
<img src="non-existent.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
```

but that one works:

```
<img src="non-existent.jpg" alt="WSchools.com" width="104" height="142">
```

Could you please explain why?

I use Google Chrome and Windows 8.1. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I got the reason why you were not able to see the alt text. I have updated my answer. Check @semiliranda

Comment: What are you talking about? “Until it contains a number” makes no sense and is even inconsistent with what you say about your example (where you claim the version *without* a digit to “work”).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

string present in alt is displayed only when the image fails to load, or not available. Even if a number is there alt will show it.

What you are mentioning about not getting displayed is under one condition

> If the text fits the width of the image, it will be displayed, else it
>   will not be visible.

Both of your provided code works.

```
<img src="non-existent.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142"> // works

<img src="non-existent.jpg" alt="WSchools.com" width="104" height="142"> // works 

<img src="non-existent.jpg" alt="W3535Schools.com" width="104" height="142"> //works
```

Check this out

[Example](http://jsbin.com/dayuxesoso/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as expected with Chrome for Android. None of the 'alt' attributes display.

Comment: @Nielarshi, still does not work on Google Chrome. I checked it on IE. It works on IE.

Comment: I have mentioned that in my answer. Since the width of the image is less than width of the alt text, it is not getting displayed. Increase the width of image and check. It will work. cheers. :)

Comment: It starts working on Google Chrome with increased width, Nielarshi. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HoboSapiens : are you able to see the texts ?